# Problems running someone else's Vagrant box

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I have Vagrant installed and am trying to get someone else's box up and running and I'm getting this error:

*The provider 'parallels' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'ommitted_box_name'. Please use a provider that exists.
Vagrant knows about the following providers: docker, hyperv, virtualbox*

I have VirtualBox up and running and am not having any issues going through the basic setup on the Vagrant site, so I know the software is working.  I'm new to Vagrant and am having a rough time trying to find an answer to this question.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There is a clue right here "The provider 'parallels' could not be found"

Comment: @DavidPostill I looked up parallels because I thought I might just need an extension, but it appears that's only for Mac, unless I'm missing something.  I'm running Windows.